# Apache reverse proxy - missing content

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, centos7

here is my apache reverse proxy conf:

```
ProxyHTMLEnable On
ProxyHTMLExtended On
SetOutputFilter INFLATE;proxy-html;DEFLATE
ProxyHTMLInterp On
ProxyPass / http://10.208.202.2:8762/abc/
ProxyPassReverse / http://10.208.202.2:8762/abc/


ProxyPreserveHost On
RequestHeader set Authorization "Basic"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto "https"
RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Port "443"
```

The thing is when I enter / on my server some content is missing. For example css, some .css is supposed to be GET from /something/css/wro.css As I assume in this case content is not being downloaded because proxy actually tries to get it from /abc/something/css/wro.css which is wrong and it returns 404.
So i have tried to add:

```
ProxyPass /something http://10.208.202.2:8762/something/
ProxyPassReverse /something http://10.208.202.2:8762/something/
```

But this still does not do the trick, there is still the same css content missing.
Also I dont' see adding every location on the server manually to the configuration as a good idea. I have added proxy html mod, but it doesnt seem to do the job here.
Any suggestions what can I do, to make this work without adding proxypass entry for every location on the server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But this still does not do the trick, there is still the same css content missing

Apache processes ProxyPass directives [in the order they](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) are declared, and the first match wins. So put more specific matches first

```
ProxyPass /something http://10.208.202.2:8762/something/
ProxyPassReverse /something http://10.208.202.2:8762/something/
ProxyPass / http://10.208.202.2:8762/abc/
ProxyPassReverse / http://10.208.202.2:8762/abc/
```

is the necessary order otherwise the `/something` is never matched.

> Any suggestions what can I do, to make this work without adding proxypass entry for every location on the server?

Basically, if you want a different file structure to be served, than is present on the proxied location, then generally you are going to have to write a ProxyPass for every exception to the default.

If what you are trying to achieve is to make `http://10.208.202.2:8762/abc/index.html` the default page on your website, you might be better to do that with a redirect, otherwise it will mess up your page relative links. Something like this should work;

```
RedirectMatch ^/$ /abc/
```

Comment: Hi Tom! Thanks for your reply Actually I'm using this whole thing as an authentication and authorization service based on Kerberos and LDAP, so  the idea is to limit access to http://10.208.202.2:8762/abc/ and other services using one server. So I just want to make it easily scalable when adding new sites, so I wont have to manually configure every new site so precisely.